# Why isn't my image being found in Pygame?

Tags: python

I was working on a space shooter game when I can across this problem:

```
  File "C:\Users\willi\PycharmProjects\Pygame Testing\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    icon = pygame.image.load("Images", "boss.png")
FileNotFoundError: No file 'Images' found in working directory 'C:\Users\willi\PycharmProjects\Pygame Testing'.
```

I am working in PyCharm where i created a directory called "Images" and I put all my icons and enemies. I wanted to put the boss as the icon but it didn't work. Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to note here:

1. You do not need to specify the first parameter to be `"Images"`. Just the path to the file will do (make sure that the path is relative to your current directory.) You can read up more about the `pygame.image.load`  function [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load)
2. PyGame sometimes tends to misbehave with normal variables. It is always a good idea to make them `global` in the main scope.

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.image.load` takes in a filename as the first argument

`'Images'` is not a filename. Use `icon = pygame.image.load("Images/boss.png")`

([Read the docs here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load))